# UITableViewCell wrong content width

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i'm using tableview in iOS 9, Swift 2
I don't understand why , when i create a table view with simple cells, i get a wrong width of the contentview, even if i set container view to 1000.
The cell width is exactly 1000, but the textLabel inside is less than 1000. Also separators are centered and with wrong width.

How can i get my cells displayed correctly , and covering the entire container view?

Everything is created programmatically.

Here is my code:

```
    if tableView == nil {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44/*88*/, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height - 44/*88*/), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        tableView!.delegate = self
        tableView!.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        tableView!.dataSource = self
        tableView!.rowHeight = 40.0
        tableView!.allowsSelection = false
        tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        view.addSubview(tableView!)

        tableView!.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var MyIdentifier: String = "MyReuseIdentifier"
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(MyIdentifier)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: MyIdentifier)
    }
    cell!.textLabel!.text = "Test"
    cell!.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
    cell!.textLabel!.textColor = .blackColor()
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Is your container view main view controller `view`?

Comment: Try to update the frame values of "textLabel".

Comment: here is the hierarchy:
- viewController (not main but another one) with its own view
- tableView that is a subview of viewcontroller view.

Answer (score 2):

```
tableView!.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

This is the solution!

It is not necessary to set contentInsets.

Answer (score 1):

While the cells's width is the width of the entire view, it's content view is inset on all sides by (I think) 8 points, so it makes sense for the label not to be across the whole screen

To have a label that goes across the entire width of the screen create a custom cell class and add constraints to its label to account for this. (Label's leading to content view leading = -8.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can check

```
tableView.contentInset
```

And then update left inset. Also, check that you have not given any constraint, like leadingSpace. Or margin to the UITableView itself. Similarly you have

```
cell.separatorInset
```

By default there is left padding of 5, so make this 0.

Comment: tried both, not working.. i see only separators between cells that now reach the end of the cell... but the textLabel is still "centered", and not starting from x=0

Comment: then try setting layoutMargins, tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO; If this is specific to ios 9.